Why JSON method isn't working anymore on my program?
I made this program a few month ago and it was fine. Now i tried to run it and i'm getting JSONDecodeError. I tried another url's and so it wasn't working either. However, url's with json extensions are working. Can someone help me with this?
import sys
import random
import pyfiglet
import requests
import json
list=[]
if len(sys.argv)<=3:
    responce=requests.get('https://github.com/pwaller/pyfiglet/tree/main/pyfiglet/fonts-standard')
    o=responce.json()
    x=o["payload"]["tree"]["items"]
    for i in x:
       list.append(i["name"])
    responce1=requests.get('https://github.com/pwaller/pyfiglet/tree/main/pyfiglet/fonts-contrib')
    o1=responce1.json()
    y=o1["payload"]["tree"]["items"]
    for i1 in y:
       list.append(i1["name"])
    if len(sys.argv)==1:
        z=random.choice(list)
        z=z[0:-4]
        v=input('Input: ')
        print('Output:\n'+pyfiglet.figlet_format(v, font=z))
        sys.exit()
    if len(sys.argv)==3:
        if (sys.argv[1]=='-f' or sys.argv[1]=='--font'):
            for font in list:
                if font[0:-4]==sys.argv[2]:
                    n=input('Input: ')
                    print('Output:\n'+pyfiglet.figlet_format(n, font=sys.argv[2]))
                    sys.exit()
                else:
                    continue
            sys.exit('Invalid usage')
        else:
            sys.exit('Invalid usage')
    else:
        sys.exit('Invalid usage')
else:
    sys.exit('Invalid usage')    

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tonib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 971, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tonib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tonib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tonib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pythonproj\indoor.py", line 9, in <module>
    o=responce.json()
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tonib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 975, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 7 column 1 (char 6)


That URL doesn't return JSON. It's a normal HTML web page.

You can put it into a web browser and you'll see.

somehow it was working in the past and i have this program on my github, anyway  how can i extract keys and values from this page?

This code has lots of errors.  First, there is no closing parentheses for the print call, so this code wouldn't even run.  Second, you're calling .json() on the url string itself, not on the respose object.  There's no way this is your real code.  Please post the real code.

You've probably changed the URL. It's not clear what JSON you're expecting to get from that URL.

And paste the traceback as text, not an image.

You don't need to import json to use the response.json() method.

so i corrected my question, hope it'll help

As @Barmar said, that url simply does not return json.  I don't see any way to help further.

so how could it work before? is url settings may be changed somehow or...? i'm really confused on this

Possibly that url used to return json, and now it doesn't?

@JohnGordon It's a github.com URL to a repository, it's unlikely it has changed. The URL in the code probably changed.

See https://docs.github.com/en/rest/git/trees?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-tree-recursively for the documentation of the REST API for fetching information about a github repository.
